# Ubuntu1904: Can't start files or terminal

Tags: 19.04

My ubuntu install is literally just hours old and I can't open the files or terminal app anymore, I literally installed chrome, played around in ubuntu apps, turned off yesterday and today trying to start these apps just gives me the beachball.

At one point I got the "can't start preferred applications" error but now it doesn't show anymore.

I've got 19.04 x64 uefi install, default desktop.
Can ofc install other terminals or file managers but would really prefer to go vanilla for starters before feeling the need to explore.

Anyone know off the bat what it could be, or how I could find out more info to share here?

Thanks

Comment: if you're a somewhat experienced user and would like to investigate the issue, one alternative would be to open a new terminal and try to invoke the gui apps from there, and see what errors it throws. To open the new terminal, you'd do something like CTRL+ALT+F2. Then, set the display with `export DISPLAY=:0`. Then call the terminal from your command line. I'm saying these things off of my head, so I might be mistaken somewhere. I personally would probably just re-install... in my experience, linux installations are quite non-deterministic. lol :(

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, the only issue is I can't open a new terminal, but I should be able to try that with an alternative terminal like terminology. I'll test it and see what that gives. Cheers

Comment: Ok I tried to run /usr/bin/gnome-terminal from terminology after setting export DISPLAY=:0 and it says: Invalid MIT-MAGIC-COOKIE-1 keyUnable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
# Failed to parse arguments: Cannot open display:

I take that as the export display-thing didn't work rather than an error message? Other ideas?

Comment: Mm. Usually the "cannot open display" message is followed by the display it tried to open; in this case, it should say "cannot open display: :0". If you do `echo $DISPLAY` does it output `:0`? are you in bash? you could also try `:0.0` as the value for DISPLAY. Or try to find which display your X is running. I don't remember how to do that. In any case, since you're trying to start it from a terminal that's already running on X, you wouldn't need to set the display, that was for trying to open things from the console terminal.